# What verb forms εἴσηκται as 3 s pf m/p?

Tags: greek, verbs, perfect-tense

I’m certain the form εἴσηκται is 3rd sing. perfect M/P but can’t for the life of me come up with what verb this is. Does anyone recognize this? Is it a misprint, or am I forgetting something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Perseus's morphology tool](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=eishktai&la=greek), this form comes from the compound [*εἰσ-άγω*, "to lead into"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dei)sa%2Fgw).

Comment: Okay, I wondered about that, but decided it must be something else because of the active form εἰσαγήγοχα. I’ll accept your answer, thanks.

Comment: That's a handy tool, bookmarking it now